# Windows XP rebooting before logon

Tags: windows

as title, any ideas what I can do? I can't get into safe mode either and it's just stuck in a constant loop of rebooting!

No error codes or anything?

Comment: Have seen this a number of times, often after an update.  Sme suggest this is malware but have seen this after a fresh install. Scan of the HD on a second system found no malware of any kind. Have never found a good solution. Hope someone has an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

boot from a windows CD into the recovery console and run: chkdsk c: /r

> No error codes or anything?

the problem is that your system is set to automatically restart rather than producing a crash dump (BSOD). so, in the future clear the Automatic restart upon system failure (advanced system properties > startup & recovery).

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I had this problem. The computer crashed because of a blackout. You just saved my life!! Thanks!!!

Comment: you're more than welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this sort of problem caused by a bad video card or its driver, a hardware conflict between seemingly unrelated devices, or even a bad power supply.

- If your computer has an multiple video cards, remove one and see whether Windows allows you to log on.  You could fall back to an integrated card if your computer has one.
- If you recently installed any new hardware, remove it and see whether Windows allows you to log on.
- You might try switching out your power supply for a known-good power supply.  Many times it seems that a dying power supply has enough 'juice' to get through the early stages of booting, but not enough to run the video card at a higher resolution and quicker refresh rate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently added new memory or just finished building the computer?
**If so read-on, otherwise, ignore.**

I had this problem with a clean install of Win XP x64 with newly installed memory that the board couldn't handle.

I don't know how this wouldn't have been caught earlier in the boot process, but the XP spash screen would show and then reboot.

After checking out the motherboard manufactures website, I changed the voltage for my RAM and it solved the issue.